# Android Kotlin error : "return type is 'unit' which is not a subtype of overridden"

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to pop out an alert box which asks the user if he wants to delete a value from an ArrayList which is displayed in a ListView whenever he attemps to make a long click on one of them

```
mainListView.setLongClickable(true)
mainListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(object: AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {
        override fun onItemLongClick(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position:Int, id:Long) {
           val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@listV)
           alertDialog.setTitle("Would you like to delete this ?")
           alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes") { dialog, whichButton -> mobileArray.removeAt(position);listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() }
           alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", { dialog, which ->  })
           alertDialog.create()
           alertDialog.show()}})
```

but there's an error on the OnItemLongClick function which is

> return type is 'unit' which is not a subtype of overridden
>   public abstract fun onItemLongClick(...): Boolean defined in android.widget.adapterView.OnItemLongClickListener

I'm very confused since I used pretty much the same code for a simple "onItemClick" and it worked fine

Comment: What does your {dialog, which -> ...} map to? I mean the one for "Cancel"

Comment: Nothing, it quits the dialog alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signatures of [`onItemClick`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E%2C%20android.view.View%2C%20int%2C%20long)) and [`onItemLongClick`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html#onItemLongClick(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E%2C%20android.view.View%2C%20int%2C%20long)) differ (which, granted, is an odd inconsistency in the API):

```
void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

The latter returns a `boolean` value indicating whether the event has been consumed by the listener. If this is `true`, other listeners won't get called for this event.

So what you want to do is something like this:

```
override fun onItemLongClick(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long): Boolean {
    // alert dialog code
    return true
}
```